# App Metrics endpoints not showing up on prometheus /graph

Tags: c#, docker, prometheus, grafana, portainer

I have an **.NET 5** API and I downloaded Prometheus and App.Metrics NuGet packages:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="App.Metrics.AspNetCore" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="App.Metrics.AspNetCore.All" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="App.Metrics.Formatters.Prometheus" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="App.Metrics.Prometheus" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="prometheus-net" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="prometheus-net.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My StartUp.cs looks like this:

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMetrics();
            services.AddSingleton<MetricReporter>();

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API.TEST.METRICS", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API.TEST.METRICS v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            //app.UseHttpMetrics();
            app.UseMiddleware<MetricMiddleware>();
            app.UseMetricServer();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

and my Program.cs:

```cs
    public class Program
    {
        public static IMetricsRoot Metrics { get; set; }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            Metrics = AppMetrics.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                    .OutputMetrics.AsPrometheusPlainText()
                    .OutputMetrics.AsPrometheusProtobuf()
                    .Build();

            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                            .ConfigureMetrics(Metrics)
                            .UseMetrics(
                                options =>
                                {
                                    options.EndpointOptions = endpointsOptions =>
                                    {
                                        endpointsOptions.MetricsTextEndpointOutputFormatter = Metrics.OutputMetricsFormatters.OfType<MetricsPrometheusTextOutputFormatter>().First();
                                        endpointsOptions.MetricsEndpointOutputFormatter = Metrics.OutputMetricsFormatters.OfType<MetricsPrometheusProtobufOutputFormatter>().First();
                                    };
                                })
                            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                            {
                                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                            });
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the application endpoint's metrics is `/metrics` for protobuf and `/metrics-text` for text format. With that being said, I've created a MetricReporter.cs:

```cs
    public class MetricReporter
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MetricReporter> _logger;
        private readonly Counter _requestCounter;
        private readonly Histogram _responseTimeHistogram;

        public MetricReporter(ILogger<MetricReporter> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));

            _requestCounter =
                Metrics.CreateCounter("total_requests", "The total number of requests serviced by this API.");

            _responseTimeHistogram = Metrics.CreateHistogram("request_duration_seconds",
                "The duration in seconds between the response to a request.", new HistogramConfiguration
                {
                    Buckets = Histogram.ExponentialBuckets(0.01, 2, 10),
                    LabelNames = new[] { "status_code", "method" }
                });
        }

        public void RegisterRequest()
        {
            _requestCounter.Inc();
        }

        public void RegisterResponseTime(int statusCode, string method, TimeSpan elapsed)
        {
            _responseTimeHistogram.Labels(statusCode.ToString(), method).Observe(elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        }
    }
```

and a Middleware:

```cs
    public class MetricMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _request;

        public MetricMiddleware(RequestDelegate request)
        {
            _request = request ?? throw new Exception(string.Format("Context is empty; {0}", nameof(request)));
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, MetricReporter reporter)
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.Value == "/metrics-text")
            {
                await _request.Invoke(context);
                return;
            }
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            try
            {
                await _request.Invoke(context);
            }
            finally
            {
                sw.Stop();
                reporter.RegisterRequest();
                reporter.RegisterResponseTime(context.Response.StatusCode, context.Request.Method, sw.Elapsed);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the application and call the API's controller (route: `/test`) I call clearly see the App.Metrics endpoint being called on my `application/metrics-text` endpoint.

```
# HELP application_httprequests_apdex 
# TYPE application_httprequests_apdex gauge
application_httprequests_apdex{server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 1

# HELP application_httprequests_one_minute_error_percentage_rate_per_endpoint 
# TYPE application_httprequests_one_minute_error_percentage_rate_per_endpoint gauge
application_httprequests_one_minute_error_percentage_rate_per_endpoint{route="GET",server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 0

# HELP application_httprequests_one_minute_error_percentage_rate 
# TYPE application_httprequests_one_minute_error_percentage_rate gauge
application_httprequests_one_minute_error_percentage_rate{server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 0

# HELP application_httprequests_active 
# TYPE application_httprequests_active gauge
application_httprequests_active{server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 0

# HELP application_httprequests_errors 
# TYPE application_httprequests_errors gauge
application_httprequests_errors{http_status_code="404",server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 0

# HELP application_httprequests_error_rate_per_endpoint_and_status_code_total 
# TYPE application_httprequests_error_rate_per_endpoint_and_status_code_total counter
application_httprequests_error_rate_per_endpoint_and_status_code_total{route="GET",http_status_code="404",server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 2

# HELP application_httprequests_error_rate_per_endpoint_total 
# TYPE application_httprequests_error_rate_per_endpoint_total counter
application_httprequests_error_rate_per_endpoint_total{route="GET",server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 2

# HELP application_httprequests_error_rate_total 
# TYPE application_httprequests_error_rate_total counter
application_httprequests_error_rate_total{server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 2

# HELP application_httprequests_transactions_per_endpoint 
# TYPE application_httprequests_transactions_per_endpoint summary
application_httprequests_transactions_per_endpoint_sum{route="GET",server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 0
application_httprequests_transactions_per_endpoint_count{route="GET",server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 0
application_httprequests_transactions_per_endpoint{route="GET",server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development",quantile="0.5"} 0
application_httprequests_transactions_per_endpoint{route="GET",server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development",quantile="0.75"} 0
application_httprequests_transactions_per_endpoint{route="GET",server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development",quantile="0.95"} 0
application_httprequests_transactions_per_endpoint{route="GET",server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development",quantile="0.99"} 0

# HELP application_httprequests_transactions 
# TYPE application_httprequests_transactions summary
application_httprequests_transactions_sum{server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 0.0081703
application_httprequests_transactions_count{server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development"} 21
application_httprequests_transactions{server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development",quantile="0.5"} 0.0081703
application_httprequests_transactions{server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development",quantile="0.75"} 0.0081703
application_httprequests_transactions{server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development",quantile="0.95"} 0.0081703
application_httprequests_transactions{server="e4073c323432",app="API.TEST.METRICS",env="development",quantile="0.99"} 0.0081703
```

But when I go to the prometheus `:9090/graph` (localhost) endpoint, I can't see the **application_httprequests_...** in the auto-complete textbox either in the grafana dashboard.

[image]

I'm running both grafana and prometheus on docker. I have a stack (in portainer.io) with prometheus, grafana, node_exporter and cAdvisor.

```yaml
---
version: '3'

volumes:
  prometheus-data:
    driver: local
  grafana-data:
    driver: local

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - /etc/prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus-data:/prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana
    restart: unless-stopped
    
  node_exporter:
    image: quay.io/prometheus/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: node_exporter
    command:
      - '--path.rootfs=/host'
    pid: host
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - '/:/host:ro,rslave'
      
  cadvisor:
    image: google/cadvisor:latest
    container_name: cadvisor
    # ports:
    #   - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:ro
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
      - /dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro
    devices:
      - /dev/kmsg
```

And my `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` file is configured like that:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with                                                                                                                                     
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).                                                                                                                                                 
  # external_labels:                                                                                                                                                                                             
  #  monitor: 'codelab-monitor'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  # A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:                                                                                                                                            
  # Here it's Prometheus itself.                                                                                                                                                                                 scrape_configs:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.                                                                                                                
  - job_name: 'prometheus'                                                                                                                                                                                         
  # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.                                                                                                                                
    scrape_interval: 5s                                                                                                                                                                                            
    static_configs:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  # Example job for node_exporter                                                                                                                                                                                
  - job_name: 'node_exporter'                                                                                                                                                                                      
    static_configs:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    - targets: ['node_exporter:9100']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  # Example job for cadvisor                                                                                                                                                                                     
  - job_name: 'cadvisor'                                                                                                                                                                                           
    static_configs:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    - targets: ['cadvisor:8080']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  # Example job for the application (API.TEST.METRICS)                                                                                                                                                           
  - job_name: 'metrics_test_app'                                                                                                                                                                                   
    static_configs:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    - targets: ['localhost:49159']                                                                                                                                                                               
    metrics_path: '/metrics-text'                                                                                                                                                                                  
    scheme: https
```

I believe the problem is in the way I configured the application in the `prometheus.yml` file, because **node_exporter** and **cadvisor** metrics are being sent to grafana and I can see both of them in the `localhost:9090/graph` (prometheus endpoint).

I'm really out of ideas on how to solve this problem. I'm new to docker and prometheus.

Comment: I think that you either use App.Metrics or prometheus-net.AspNetCore, not both. If you want to expose endpoints and requests I suggest to use prometheus-net.AspNetCore only, you can try to search in youtube for that topic there are really good videos for that for both and see the difference.